Increase the test performance avoiding the use of mock.create_autospec()
I have created a class called RedisCliWrapper which contains many methods that call methods of the class redis.Redis. Below I show the class with only the method get_hgetall_value(), which is one of its many methods:
from redis import Redis

class RedisCliWrapper:
    
    def __init__(self, redis_cli_instance : Redis):
        self.__redis_cli_instance : Redis = redis_cli_instance
        
    def get_hgetall_value(self, key):
        return self.__redis_cli_instance.hgetall(key)

As the code shows, when I create an instance of RedisCliWrapper I have to pass an instance of the class redis.Redis.
To test the RedisCliWrapper I have created the following:
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import redis
from redis_cli_wrapper import RedisCliWrapper

class RedisCliWrapperTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_redis_cli = mock.create_autospec(redis.Redis)
        #self.mock_redis_cli = mock.Mock()
        self.sut = RedisCliWrapper(self.mock_redis_cli)

    def test_something_1(self):
        self.mock_redis_cli.hgetall.return_value = {'f1': 'value1', 'f2': 'value2'}
        self.sut.get_hgetall_value('key1')
        self.mock_redis_cli.hgetall.assert_called_once_with('key1')

    def test_something_2(self):
        self.mock_redis_cli.hgetall.return_value = {'f21': 'value21', 'f22': 'value22'}
        self.sut.get_hgetall_value('key2')
        self.mock_redis_cli.hgetall.assert_called_once_with('key2')

    def test_something_3(self):
        self.mock_redis_cli.hgetall.return_value = {'f1': 'value1', 'f2': 'value2'}
        self.assertDictEqual({'f1': 'value1', 'f2': 'value2'}, self.sut.get_hgetall_value('key1'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

The attribute mock_redis_cli is instantiated by the use of the function mock.create_autospec():
self.mock_redis_cli = mock.create_autospec(redis.Redis)

If I execute the 3 tests, I obtain the following output:
> python test_redis_cli_wrapper.py
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.495s

OK

which shows that the 3 tests are execute in 0.495s (the execution of my real test code takes about 40 seconds).
However, if I instantiate the attribute mock_redis_cli by the following instruction:
self.mock_redis_cli = mock.Mock()

the output of the execution of the 3 tests is the following:
> python test_redis_cli_wrapper.py
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK

so the 3 tests are executed in only 1ms (the execution of my real test code with the use of mock.Mock() instead of mock.create_autospec(redis.Redis) takes about 0.130 seconds).
The time execution difference is enormous so in my context it is recommended to use mock.create_autospec(redis.Redis) or can I use the faster mock.Mock()?

It's surely inevitable that the autospec'd version is slower - it has to do quite a bit more work to (attempt to) ensure that interactions with the test double would also be valid on the real thing, whereas without a spec (almost) anything is tolerated. Is that worth it to you is a decision other people can't make, but if you have multiple tests covering the same code you could say that only one will use the autospec (for safety) and the others won't (for speed).

Thank you. The idea to use autospec only for one of the test is very clever and could help me to find a compromise between performance and safety of the tests.
